# Does Drupal Cache work with views rendered programatically?

Tags: 7, views, caching

I want to understand does the Drupal caching work for views which are called programmatically

I am using views_get_view for my implementation plus hook_views_query_alter to further add a where condition to this view query

I am debugging this because during load testing I found this code calling memcache get request in the order of hundreds ..

**views_get_view code**

```
  $product_view = views_get_view('view_name');
  $product_view->set_display('page_1');
  $pager = array(
    'type' => 'some',
    'options' => array(
      'offset' => 0,
      'items_per_page' => 12,
    ),
  );

  if ($count != NULL) {
    $pager['items_per_page'] = $count;
  }

  $product_view->display_handler->set_option('pager', $pager);
      $product_view->display_handler->set_option('pager', $pager);

      $product_view->set_arguments([
        'abc' => TRUE,
        'xyz' => 123,
      ]);

      $product_view->some_property = $some_array;
      $product_view->execute();
      $list = $product_view->result;
```

**views query alter code**

```
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $view_args = $view->args;
  if (isset($view_args['abc']) && $view_args['abc']) {
    $some_property = $view->some_property ;
    $some_property[] = $view_args['xyz'];
    $query->add_where(1, 'node.nid', $some_property , 'NOT IN');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remember this is **Q** and A - you need to ask a question. Declaring that you have a cache issue, but not explaining what the issue is, or what you've done so far to debug the problem, doesn't make for a useful post for future users. Please take some time to write a specific, detailed post about the problem you're facing

Comment: Please review again

Comment: Looks good but i think you could define the issue a bit further - for example, why are you mentioning memcache speeds? Is that relevant to the problem? An example of the problem? Something else? If you've identified that memcache is being hit, surely you've answered your own question, and yes, programatically generated views are cached?